# Logger Rate Limiter

Tags: algorithm

Design a logger system that receive stream of messages along with its timestamps, each message should be printed if and only if it is not printed in the last 10 seconds.

Given a message and a timestamp (in seconds granularity), return true if the message should be printed in the given timestamp, otherwise returns false.

It is possible that several messages arrive roughly at the same time

Example:
Logger logger = new Logger();

// logging string "foo" at timestamp 1
logger.shouldPrintMessage(1, "foo"); returns true;

// logging string "bar" at timestamp 2
logger.shouldPrintMessage(2,"bar"); returns true;

// logging string "foo" at timestamp 3
logger.shouldPrintMessage(3,"foo"); returns false;

// logging string "bar" at timestamp 8
logger.shouldPrintMessage(8,"bar"); returns false;

// logging string "foo" at timestamp 10
logger.shouldPrintMessage(10,"foo"); returns false;

// logging string "foo" at timestamp 11
logger.shouldPrintMessage(11,"foo"); returns true;

Please tell approach and about the question. I don't get it thanks.

Comment: Looks like home work. If you don't understand the exercise it is best to ask your instructor.

Comment: Use a HashMap. It will be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> each message should be printed if and only if it is not printed in the last 10 seconds

This implies that the logger has to keep track of which messages were printed in the last 10 seconds (or more).

This could be done with (e.g.) a linked list of messages, such that when a message is received you discard any messages in the list that have become older than 10 seconds, then check if the new message is the same as something that's still in the list to decide whether to ignore the new message or print the new message and add it to the list.

Comment: thanks a lot, i done it using hashing but linked list can do same

Answer (score 0):

**Designed it using HashMap to keep track of time and message:**
We check if difference between the time stored in hashmap
and current timestamp is less then we will return false else we update the hashmap with current timestamp.

**Below is the solution:**

class Logger {

```
/** Initialize your data structure here. */
private HashMap<String, Integer> map;
public Logger() {
 map = new HashMap<>();
}

/** Returns true if the message should be printed in the given timestamp, otherwise returns false.
    If this method returns false, the message will not be printed.
    The timestamp is in seconds granularity. */
public boolean shouldPrintMessage(int timestamp, String message) {
    if (!map.containsKey(message)) {
        map.put(message, timestamp);
        return true;
    }
    
    int t1 = map.get(message);
    if (timestamp-t1 < 10) {
        return false;
    }
    map.put(message, timestamp);
    return true;
}
```

}

/**

- Your Logger object will be instantiated and called as such:
- Logger obj = new Logger();
- boolean param_1 = obj.shouldPrintMessage(timestamp,message);
  */